# Return API request value automatically in rails with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, api, cron

I have this Jquery code in my application.js file where when the `<p id="kraken_btc_eur">` is clicked it return a value fetch from an API. 
This code works but I want it to work automatically, without having to click. I tried `setInterval()` but it does not seem to work as it does not update the value. The value I am trying to return change constantly in the API that is why I would like it to be returned automatically, the same way you can see in stock market websites.

```
$('#kraken_btc_eur').click(function(){
  $.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR', function(data){
    var kraken_btc_eur = data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0]
    $("#kraken_btc_eur").html("<p>"+kraken_btc_eur+"</p>");
    // console.log(data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0]);
  })
});
```

Many thanks for yur guidance.

Comment: So you want it to be executed once or every x seconds?

Comment: yes automatically every 10 sec, so it can fetch the new most accurate value

Comment: I was using a gem called httparty to fetch API data however I realize that the value change constantly so I need to fetch the value constantly but I do not want the page to refresh. i know it sounds like an AJAX call, i understand AJAX for CRUD action but not for fetching api based value, is it a thing?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a rails question... What do you want to trigger your function? Load? Click?

Comment: I want that code above to be executed without having to be clicked. In other words, I want the variable 'var kraken_btc_eur' to update itself every 3 seconds and append the html with the updated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR', function(data){
            $("#kraken_btc_eur p").text(data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0]);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

PS. I would suggest to improve it further by calling the next update on ajax call finish.

Comment: It does not work and trigger an error. It seems that having a click event inside a setinterval does not work. Could you give me an exemple of an ajax call?

Comment: thank so much it is great, could you explain why the '.text()' and not '.html()' ? Also it creates new ressources, every 10 sec, is there a way to remove the old ones ? or maybe ressources it does not matter. i just wonder if the old ressources are stored somewhere and would use space.

Comment: Re: `text`, it's small improvement. It sets the text value without trying to add parse and add HTML tags. It is minor performance improvement. You may choose to use `.html()` instead. As for the "resources", I didn't quite got what you mean.

Comment: thanks for your guidance. For the ressources, its just that in the safari "inspect element"  i can see that every time the setInterval function is triggered it shows a new "ressource" in the "ressources" tab, i was just wondering if it is stored somewhere or i can just ignore it. But I guess that should be another question. thank you so much.